# css pdf: force page break on overflow content

Tags: javascript, html, css, handlebars.js, puppeteer

I'm using handlebars and puppeteer to generate a pdf. The pdf is very design heavy with a lot of dynamic data so I'm using css to mock out the A4 formatted pages but I've reached a point where the data size is no longer predictable due to user input. By this I mean, if the data overflows beyond the pages bottom constraint, it keeps going into the void rather than automatically break out into the next page. My question is, is there a way to see if the page content is beyond the constraints of the parent, and if so.. break it out into another div/page with css or JavaScript?

Here is a small mockup of what my code looks like.
https://codepen.io/LTFoReal/pen/wvKboNJ

```css
body {
  background: rgb(204,204,204); 
}
page {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
page[size="A4"] {  
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm; 
  padding: 5em 30px 0 30px;
  position: relative;
}

@media print {
  body, page {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}

.essay-data-container {
    min-height: 300px;
}

.essay-data-container .essay-data-header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<page size="A4">
      <h1>A RANDOM HEADER</h1>
      <div class="essay-data-container">
        <h4 class="essay-data-header">This is the sub-title</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In euismod luctus neque, eu pulvinar ante elementum vel. Pellentesque rutrum sapien vitae neque ornare, id vehicula nibh fermentum. Aliquam accumsan dictum gravida. Integer nec molestie mauris, sit amet placerat risus. Nam dolor dui, fringilla ac fermentum ac, mattis non enim. Vestibulum porttitor justo sed arcu porta dapibus. Suspendisse varius eros et ante ultricies congue. Nam magna ante, ornare sed tincidunt eget, euismod et nunc. Suspendisse venenatis aliquet ex et lacinia. Curabitur vitae ornare nibh. Suspendisse hendrerit fermentum egestas. Duis in nibh eros.
</p></li>
          <li><p>Phasellus eu imperdiet mauris. Nam iaculis metus eget nisi volutpat mollis. Praesent luctus nulla non lacus porta, nec cursus lorem eleifend. Quisque libero justo, fringilla vitae vestibulum in, bibendum vehicula justo. Fusce non leo porttitor, consequat enim vitae, luctus lacus. Nulla in sollicitudin quam, in vestibulum nisl. Etiam congue metus nunc, a tincidunt diam lobortis quis. Ut sodales mi magna, sit amet suscipit tellus semper id. Sed mattis efficitur justo eget tincidunt. Mauris vel commodo velit. Fusce augue magna, faucibus id venenatis sit amet, luctus id neque. Maecenas sed justo pellentesque, porttitor eros at, lobortis est. Nunc fringilla nisi eget erat aliquet, non tristique nulla imperdiet. Proin posuere elementum elit. Praesent massa massa, condimentum et consectetur non, ullamcorper et odio.
</p></li>
          <li><p>Nunc malesuada eu leo eget bibendum. Sed vitae justo euismod, vestibulum tortor sit amet, cursus augue. Nunc aliquet ullamcorper mollis. Nulla blandit porttitor tempor. Curabitur egestas dolor a enim lobortis iaculis sit amet non enim. Vestibulum sagittis est sollicitudin eros elementum, a pulvinar ante euismod. Phasellus pulvinar rhoncus tortor eget congue. Integer mattis vestibulum ex sit amet pulvinar. Praesent luctus felis urna, at bibendum justo eleifend ut. Nullam facilisis faucibus arcu, nec ultrices turpis consequat nec. Aliquam in lacus libero. Praesent tempor malesuada rutrum. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean nec ligula nisi.
</p></li>
          <li><p>Quisque a faucibus nibh. Vestibulum faucibus elit a elementum semper. Phasellus ac felis porta, finibus nibh gravida, fermentum metus. Donec a mauris dui. Morbi a turpis ac augue commodo ornare quis auctor purus. Cras consectetur turpis at nisi hendrerit gravida. Duis auctor faucibus mi, at hendrerit justo scelerisque in. Morbi bibendum leo sed arcu ultricies, a varius ante maximus. Donec molestie orci id rhoncus aliquam. Morbi id sodales elit.
</p></li>
          <li><p>Aenean viverra iaculis ante, nec sodales ipsum tempor a. Fusce risus nisl, aliquet quis arcu quis, consequat faucibus nibh. Aliquam eu pellentesque nulla, sed cursus leo. Vestibulum vel nibh orci. Phasellus vitae lacinia nulla. Ut at magna mollis, venenatis metus quis, ultricies enim. Integer ullamcorper sit amet magna at interdum. Pellentesque a mauris nec sem condimentum tincidunt. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In ac lectus vitae eros aliquam condimentum. Donec luctus ullamcorper neque, ut lobortis odio aliquet ut.
</p></li>
          <li><p>
            Nulla ornare eros vel mattis feugiat. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed vitae dolor velit. Aliquam egestas pharetra accumsan. Integer lobortis massa nec felis egestas, quis finibus neque aliquam. Integer consectetur nibh augue, at ultrices sem sagittis vel. Aliquam eu venenatis neque. Fusce aliquet sem ac lorem fringilla, malesuada luctus risus sodales. Mauris sed lectus ut tellus rhoncus lacinia. Pellentesque ultrices condimentum leo eu pharetra. Maecenas sit amet tortor at nisl mollis accumsan. Etiam volutpat tortor et libero mollis, ut facilisis massa feugiat.
            </p></li>
          <li><p>
            Integer sodales lorem ac fringilla ornare. Fusce ac ultrices odio. Maecenas aliquam orci ac urna egestas placerat. Maecenas lacus massa, dictum vitae felis vel, semper elementum urna. Curabitur eu ex sed ex varius aliquam eget ut sapien. Sed ac tellus quis arcu hendrerit hendrerit a ac dui. Nunc tortor libero, consequat ut ligula at, suscipit mollis ante. Ut ultrices id libero in congue. Nunc a justo scelerisque, finibus lacus at, pellentesque dolor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse eget dignissim magna. Integer efficitur risus vitae leo blandit semper.
            </p></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</page>
<page size="A4"></page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I manage to do. It's not perfect but works fine for these two pages, and with some extra javascript you can make this work for the entire pdf.

Basically I check if it's overflowing based on the client/scroll width and height. Here is the place that I get inspiration and most of the code for check the overflow https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-determine-the-content-of-html-elements-overflow-or-not/

Then, I get the li tags that are overflowing and push into a new array called removedLis. After that, I just append this removedLis on the next page

--**EDIT**

Now it's working with countless pages

You can test here https://codepen.io/paulodelia/pen/ZEbNKBX

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        How to determine the content of
        HTML elements overflow or not
    </title>

    <style>
        body {
            background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
        }

        page {
            background: white;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            page-break-before: always;
        }

        page[size="A4"] {
            width: 21cm;
            height: 29.7cm;
            max-height: 29.7cm;
            padding: 5em 30px 0 30px;
            position: relative;
        }

        @media print {

            body,
            page {
                margin: 0;
                box-shadow: 0;
            }
        }

        .essay-data-container {
            min-height: 300px;
            max-height: 400px;
        }

        .essay-data-container .essay-data-header {
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        ul {
            height: 25cm;
        }

        @media all {
            .page-break {
                display: block;
                page-break-before: always;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body onload="gfg_Run()">
    <page size="A4">
        <h1>A RANDOM HEADER</h1>
        <div class="essay-data-container">
            <h4 class="essay-data-header">This is the sub-title</h4>
            <ul class="GFG_UP">
                <li>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In euismod luctus neque, eu pulvinar
                        ante elementum vel. Pellentesque rutrum sapien vitae neque ornare, id vehicula nibh fermentum.
                        Aliquam accumsan dictum gravida. Integer nec molestie mauris, sit amet placerat risus. Nam dolor
                        dui, fringilla ac fermentum ac, mattis non enim. Vestibulum porttitor justo sed arcu porta
                        dapibus. Suspendisse varius eros et ante ultricies congue. Nam magna ante, ornare sed tincidunt
                        eget, euismod et nunc. Suspendisse venenatis aliquet ex et lacinia. Curabitur vitae ornare nibh.
                        Suspendisse hendrerit fermentum egestas. Duis in nibh eros. 1
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>Phasellus eu imperdiet mauris. Nam iaculis metus eget nisi volutpat mollis. Praesent luctus nulla
                        non lacus porta, nec cursus lorem eleifend. Quisque libero justo, fringilla vitae vestibulum in,
                        bibendum vehicula justo. Fusce non leo porttitor, consequat enim vitae, luctus lacus. Nulla in
                        sollicitudin quam, in vestibulum nisl. Etiam congue metus nunc, a tincidunt diam lobortis quis.
                        Ut sodales mi magna, sit amet suscipit tellus semper id. Sed mattis efficitur justo eget
                        tincidunt. Mauris vel commodo velit. Fusce augue magna, faucibus id venenatis sit amet, luctus
                        id neque. Maecenas sed justo pellentesque, porttitor eros at, lobortis est. Nunc fringilla nisi
                        eget erat aliquet, non tristique nulla imperdiet. Proin posuere elementum elit. Praesent massa
                        massa, condimentum et consectetur non, ullamcorper et odio. 2
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>Nunc malesuada eu leo eget bibendum. Sed vitae justo euismod, vestibulum tortor sit amet, cursus
                        augue. Nunc aliquet ullamcorper mollis. Nulla blandit porttitor tempor. Curabitur egestas dolor
                        a enim lobortis iaculis sit amet non enim. Vestibulum sagittis est sollicitudin eros elementum,
                        a pulvinar ante euismod. Phasellus pulvinar rhoncus tortor eget congue. Integer mattis
                        vestibulum ex sit amet pulvinar. Praesent luctus felis urna, at bibendum justo eleifend ut.
                        Nullam facilisis faucibus arcu, nec ultrices turpis consequat nec. Aliquam in lacus libero.
                        Praesent tempor malesuada rutrum. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean nec ligula nisi. 3
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>Quisque a faucibus nibh. Vestibulum faucibus elit a elementum semper. Phasellus ac felis porta,
                        finibus nibh gravida, fermentum metus. Donec a mauris dui. Morbi a turpis ac augue commodo
                        ornare quis auctor purus. Cras consectetur turpis at nisi hendrerit gravida. Duis auctor
                        faucibus mi, at hendrerit justo scelerisque in. Morbi bibendum leo sed arcu ultricies, a varius
                        ante maximus. Donec molestie orci id rhoncus aliquam. Morbi id sodales elit. 4
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>Aenean viverra iaculis ante, nec sodales ipsum tempor a. Fusce risus nisl, aliquet quis arcu
                        quis, consequat faucibus nibh. Aliquam eu pellentesque nulla, sed cursus leo. Vestibulum vel
                        nibh orci. Phasellus vitae lacinia nulla. Ut at magna mollis, venenatis metus quis, ultricies
                        enim. Integer ullamcorper sit amet magna at interdum. Pellentesque a mauris nec sem condimentum
                        tincidunt. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
                        mus. In ac lectus vitae eros aliquam condimentum. Donec luctus ullamcorper neque, ut lobortis
                        odio aliquet ut. 5
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>
                        Nulla ornare eros vel mattis feugiat. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et
                        malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed vitae dolor velit. Aliquam egestas pharetra accumsan.
                        Integer lobortis massa nec felis egestas, quis finibus neque aliquam. Integer consectetur nibh
                        augue, at ultrices sem sagittis vel. Aliquam eu venenatis neque. Fusce aliquet sem ac lorem
                        fringilla, malesuada luctus risus sodales. Mauris sed lectus ut tellus rhoncus lacinia.
                        Pellentesque ultrices condimentum leo eu pharetra. Maecenas sit amet tortor at nisl mollis
                        accumsan. Etiam volutpat tortor et libero mollis, ut facilisis massa feugiat. 6
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>
                        Integer sodales lorem ac fringilla ornare. Fusce ac ultrices odio. Maecenas aliquam orci ac urna
                        egestas placerat. Maecenas lacus massa, dictum vitae felis vel, semper elementum urna. Curabitur
                        eu ex sed ex varius aliquam eget ut sapien. Sed ac tellus quis arcu hendrerit hendrerit a ac
                        dui. Nunc tortor libero, consequat ut ligula at, suscipit mollis ante. Ut ultrices id libero in
                        congue. Nunc a justo scelerisque, finibus lacus at, pellentesque dolor. Pellentesque habitant
                        morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse eget
                        dignissim magna. Integer efficitur risus vitae leo blandit semper. 7
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>
                        Integer sodales lorem ac fringilla ornare. Fusce ac ultrices odio. Maecenas aliquam orci ac urna
                        egestas placerat. Maecenas lacus massa, dictum vitae felis vel, semper elementum urna. Curabitur
                        eu ex sed ex varius aliquam eget ut sapien. Sed ac tellus quis arcu hendrerit hendrerit a ac
                        dui. Nunc tortor libero, consequat ut ligula at, suscipit mollis ante. Ut ultrices id libero in
                        congue. Nunc a justo scelerisque, finibus lacus at, pellentesque dolor. Pellentesque habitant
                        morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse eget
                        dignissim magna. Integer efficitur risus vitae leo blandit semper. 8
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>
                        Integer sodales lorem ac fringilla ornare. Fusce ac ultrices odio. Maecenas aliquam orci ac urna
                        egestas placerat. Maecenas lacus massa, dictum vitae felis vel, semper elementum urna. Curabitur
                        eu ex sed ex varius aliquam eget ut sapien. Sed ac tellus quis arcu hendrerit hendrerit a ac
                        dui. Nunc tortor libero, consequat ut ligula at, suscipit mollis ante. Ut ultrices id libero in
                        congue. Nunc a justo scelerisque, finibus lacus at, pellentesque dolor. Pellentesque habitant
                        morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse eget
                        dignissim magna. Integer efficitur risus vitae leo blandit semper. 9
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>
                        Integer sodales lorem ac fringilla ornare. Fusce ac ultrices odio. Maecenas aliquam orci ac urna
                        egestas placerat. Maecenas lacus massa, dictum vitae felis vel, semper elementum urna. Curabitur
                        eu ex sed ex varius aliquam eget ut sapien. Sed ac tellus quis arcu hendrerit hendrerit a ac
                        dui. Nunc tortor libero, consequat ut ligula at, suscipit mollis ante. Ut ultrices id libero in
                        congue. Nunc a justo scelerisque, finibus lacus at, pellentesque dolor. Pellentesque habitant
                        morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse eget
                        dignissim magna. Integer efficitur risus vitae leo blandit semper.10
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>
                        Integer sodales lorem ac fringilla ornare. Fusce ac ultrices odio. Maecenas aliquam orci ac urna
                        egestas placerat. Maecenas lacus massa, dictum vitae felis vel, semper elementum urna. Curabitur
                        eu ex sed ex varius aliquam eget ut sapien. Sed ac tellus quis arcu hendrerit hendrerit a ac
                        dui. Nunc tortor libero, consequat ut ligula at, suscipit mollis ante. Ut ultrices id libero in
                        congue. Nunc a justo scelerisque, finibus lacus at, pellentesque dolor. Pellentesque habitant
                        morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse eget
                        dignissim magna. Integer efficitur risus vitae leo blandit semper.11
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>
                        Integer sodales lorem ac fringilla ornare. Fusce ac ultrices odio. Maecenas aliquam orci ac urna
                        egestas placerat. Maecenas lacus massa, dictum vitae felis vel, semper elementum urna. Curabitur
                        eu ex sed ex varius aliquam eget ut sapien. Sed ac tellus quis arcu hendrerit hendrerit a ac
                        dui. Nunc tortor libero, consequat ut ligula at, suscipit mollis ante. Ut ultrices id libero in
                        congue. Nunc a justo scelerisque, finibus lacus at, pellentesque dolor. Pellentesque habitant
                        morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse eget
                        dignissim magna. Integer efficitur risus vitae leo blandit semper.12
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>
                        Integer sodales lorem ac fringilla ornare. Fusce ac ultrices odio. Maecenas aliquam orci ac urna
                        egestas placerat. Maecenas lacus massa, dictum vitae felis vel, semper elementum urna. Curabitur
                        eu ex sed ex varius aliquam eget ut sapien. Sed ac tellus quis arcu hendrerit hendrerit a ac
                        dui. Nunc tortor libero, consequat ut ligula at, suscipit mollis ante. Ut ultrices id libero in
                        congue. Nunc a justo scelerisque, finibus lacus at, pellentesque dolor. Pellentesque habitant
                        morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egesas. Suspendisse eget
                        dignissim magna. Integer efficitur risus vitae leo blandit semper.13
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>
                        Integer sodales lorem ac fringilla ornare. Fusce ac ultrices odio. Maecenas aliquam orci ac urna
                        egestas placerat. Maecenas lacus massa, dictum vitae felis vel, semper elementum urna. Curabitur
                        eu ex sed ex varius aliquam eget ut sapien. Sed ac tellus quis arcu hendrerit hendrerit a ac
                        dui. Nunc tortor libero, consequat ut ligula at, suscipit mollis ante. Ut ultrices id libero in
                        congue. Nunc a justo scelerisque, finibus lacus at, pellentesque dolor. Pellentesque habitant
                        morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egesas. Suspendisse eget
                        dignissim magna. Integer efficitur risus vitae leo blandit semper.14
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>
                        Integer sodales lorem ac fringilla ornare. Fusce ac ultrices odio. Maecenas aliquam orci ac urna
                        egestas placerat. Maecenas lacus massa, dictum vitae felis vel, semper elementum urna. Curabitur
                        eu ex sed ex varius aliquam eget ut sapien. Sed ac tellus quis arcu hendrerit hendrerit a ac
                        dui. Nunc tortor libero, consequat ut ligula at, suscipit mollis ante. Ut ultrices id libero in
                        congue. Nunc a justo scelerisque, finibus lacus at, pellentesque dolor. Pellentesque habitant
                        morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egesas. Suspendisse eget
                        dignissim magna. Integer efficitur risus vitae leo blandit semper.15
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>
                        Integer sodales lorem ac fringilla ornare. Fusce ac ultrices odio. Maecenas aliquam orci ac urna
                        egestas placerat. Maecenas lacus massa, dictum vitae felis vel, semper elementum urna. Curabitur
                        eu ex sed ex varius aliquam eget ut sapien. Sed ac tellus quis arcu hendrerit hendrerit a ac
                        dui. Nunc tortor libero, consequat ut ligula at, suscipit mollis ante. Ut ultrices id libero in
                        congue. Nunc a justo scelerisque, finibus lacus at, pellentesque dolor. Pellentesque habitant
                        morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egesas. Suspendisse eget
                        dignissim magna. Integer efficitur risus vitae leo blandit semper.16
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>
                        Integer sodales lorem ac fringilla ornare. Fusce ac ultrices odio. Maecenas aliquam orci ac urna
                        egestas placerat. Maecenas lacus massa, dictum vitae felis vel, semper elementum urna. Curabitur
                        eu ex sed ex varius aliquam eget ut sapien. Sed ac tellus quis arcu hendrerit hendrerit a ac
                        dui. Nunc tortor libero, consequat ut ligula at, suscipit mollis ante. Ut ultrices id libero in
                        congue. Nunc a justo scelerisque, finibus lacus at, pellentesque dolor. Pellentesque habitant
                        morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egesas. Suspendisse eget
                        dignissim magna. Integer efficitur risus vitae leo blandit semper.17
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>
                        Integer sodales lorem ac fringilla ornare. Fusce ac ultrices odio. Maecenas aliquam orci ac urna
                        egestas placerat. Maecenas lacus massa, dictum vitae felis vel, semper elementum urna. Curabitur
                        eu ex sed ex varius aliquam eget ut sapien. Sed ac tellus quis arcu hendrerit hendrerit a ac
                        dui. Nunc tortor libero, consequat ut ligula at, suscipit mollis ante. Ut ultrices id libero in
                        congue. Nunc a justo scelerisque, finibus lacus at, pellentesque dolor. Pellentesque habitant
                        morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egesas. Suspendisse eget
                        dignissim magna. Integer efficitur risus vitae leo blandit semper.18
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>
                        Integer sodales lorem ac fringilla ornare. Fusce ac ultrices odio. Maecenas aliquam orci ac urna
                        egestas placerat. Maecenas lacus massa, dictum vitae felis vel, semper elementum urna. Curabitur
                        eu ex sed ex varius aliquam eget ut sapien. Sed ac tellus quis arcu hendrerit hendrerit a ac
                        dui. Nunc tortor libero, consequat ut ligula at, suscipit mollis ante. Ut ultrices id libero in
                        congue. Nunc a justo scelerisque, finibus lacus at, pellentesque dolor. Pellentesque habitant
                        morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egesas. Suspendisse eget
                        dignissim magna. Integer efficitur risus vitae leo blandit semper.19
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>
                        Integer sodales lorem ac fringilla ornare. Fusce ac ultrices odio. Maecenas aliquam orci ac urna
                        egestas placerat. Maecenas lacus massa, dictum vitae felis vel, semper elementum urna. Curabitur
                        eu ex sed ex varius aliquam eget ut sapien. Sed ac tellus quis arcu hendrerit hendrerit a ac
                        dui. Nunc tortor libero, consequat ut ligula at, suscipit mollis ante. Ut ultrices id libero in
                        congue. Nunc a justo scelerisque, finibus lacus at, pellentesque dolor. Pellentesque habitant
                        morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egesas. Suspendisse eget
                        dignissim magna. Integer efficitur risus vitae leo blandit semper.20
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>
                        Integer sodales lorem ac fringilla ornare. Fusce ac ultrices odio. Maecenas aliquam orci ac urna
                        egestas placerat. Maecenas lacus massa, dictum vitae felis vel, semper elementum urna. Curabitur
                        eu ex sed ex varius aliquam eget ut sapien. Sed ac tellus quis arcu hendrerit hendrerit a ac
                        dui. Nunc tortor libero, consequat ut ligula at, suscipit mollis ante. Ut ultrices id libero in
                        congue. Nunc a justo scelerisque, finibus lacus at, pellentesque dolor. Pellentesque habitant
                        morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egesas. Suspendisse eget
                        dignissim magna. Integer efficitur risus vitae leo blandit semper.21
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>
                        Integer sodales lorem ac fringilla ornare. Fusce ac ultrices odio. Maecenas aliquam orci ac urna
                        egestas placerat. Maecenas lacus massa, dictum vitae felis vel, semper elementum urna. Curabitur
                        eu ex sed ex varius aliquam eget ut sapien. Sed ac tellus quis arcu hendrerit hendrerit a ac
                        dui. Nunc tortor libero, consequat ut ligula at, suscipit mollis ante. Ut ultrices id libero in
                        congue. Nunc a justo scelerisque, finibus lacus at, pellentesque dolor. Pellentesque habitant
                        morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egesas. Suspendisse eget
                        dignissim magna. Integer efficitur risus vitae leo blandit semper.22
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>
                        Integer sodales lorem ac fringilla ornare. Fusce ac ultrices odio. Maecenas aliquam orci ac urna
                        egestas placerat. Maecenas lacus massa, dictum vitae felis vel, semper elementum urna. Curabitur
                        eu ex sed ex varius aliquam eget ut sapien. Sed ac tellus quis arcu hendrerit hendrerit a ac
                        dui. Nunc tortor libero, consequat ut ligula at, suscipit mollis ante. Ut ultrices id libero in
                        congue. Nunc a justo scelerisque, finibus lacus at, pellentesque dolor. Pellentesque habitant
                        morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egesas. Suspendisse eget
                        dignissim magna. Integer efficitur risus vitae leo blandit semper.23
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>
                        Integer sodales lorem ac fringilla ornare. Fusce ac ultrices odio. Maecenas aliquam orci ac urna
                        egestas placerat. Maecenas lacus massa, dictum vitae felis vel, semper elementum urna. Curabitur
                        eu ex sed ex varius aliquam eget ut sapien. Sed ac tellus quis arcu hendrerit hendrerit a ac
                        dui. Nunc tortor libero, consequat ut ligula at, suscipit mollis ante. Ut ultrices id libero in
                        congue. Nunc a justo scelerisque, finibus lacus at, pellentesque dolor. Pellentesque habitant
                        morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egesas. Suspendisse eget
                        dignissim magna. Integer efficitur risus vitae leo blandit semper.24
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>
                        Integer sodales lorem ac fringilla ornare. Fusce ac ultrices odio. Maecenas aliquam orci ac urna
                        egestas placerat. Maecenas lacus massa, dictum vitae felis vel, semper elementum urna. Curabitur
                        eu ex sed ex varius aliquam eget ut sapien. Sed ac tellus quis arcu hendrerit hendrerit a ac
                        dui. Nunc tortor libero, consequat ut ligula at, suscipit mollis ante. Ut ultrices id libero in
                        congue. Nunc a justo scelerisque, finibus lacus at, pellentesque dolor. Pellentesque habitant
                        morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egesas. Suspendisse eget
                        dignissim magna. Integer efficitur risus vitae leo blandit semper.25
                    </p>
                </li>


            </ul>
        </div>
    </page>

    <script>
        var el_up = document.querySelector(".GFG_UP");

        function check(el) {
            var curOverf = el.style.overflow;

            if (!curOverf || curOverf === "visible")
                el.style.overflow = "hidden";

            var isOverflowing = el.clientWidth < el.scrollWidth
                || el.clientHeight < el.scrollHeight;

            el.style.overflow = curOverf;

            return isOverflowing;
        }

        function gfg_Run() {
            ans = "No Overflow";

            if (check(el_up)) {
                ans = "Content Overflowed";
                containOverflow(el_up);
            }
        }

        function containOverflow(el) {
            var lis = [...el.getElementsByTagName('li')];
            var removedLis = [];
            while (check(el)) {
                removedLis.push(lis.pop())
                console.log(removedLis)
                el.removeChild(el.lastElementChild)
            }
            var nextPage = document.createElement('page')
            nextPage.setAttribute('size', 'A4')
            document.querySelector('body').appendChild(nextPage);

            var nextPageUl = document.createElement('ul')
            nextPageUl.classList.add('GFG_UP')
            nextPage.appendChild(nextPageUl)

            for(let i = removedLis.length - 1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
                nextPageUl.appendChild(removedLis[i])
            }

            if (check(nextPage.querySelector('.GFG_UP'))) {
                containOverflow(nextPage.querySelector('.GFG_UP'))
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey Paulo, thanks a lot for your help. It's a good starting point for sure, the issue is now what to do about the following pages since it will need to be dynamic enough to push all of the content to a new page reguardless. Might be able to create the element and append it as a sibling to the previous page and rerun the function maybe?

Comment: Instead of getting the next page with the id, as I did in this example, you can create a new page every time that overflow and just apply the function at this new page. And if overflows again the function will create a new page and do that all over again.
"Might be able to create the element and append it as a sibling to the previous page and rerun the function maybe?" Yeah, and apply the function on this new element

Comment: I changed the code a bit and now it's working with no page limitation https://codepen.io/paulodelia/pen/ZEbNKBX

Comment: ahh never mind, I figured it out. I had to add a height to the ul to activate the clientHeight property or it would just return 0. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Just to you know, you got the old version of the code and there is some issues (mainly in that for(something / 2 ...). Here is working with the sandbox and the new update https://codesandbox.io/s/express-handlebars-g2c2f?file=/views/home.handlebars. I added some comments and changed some variables name to make a little bit better to read

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214766/discussion-between-paulo-delia-and-carlos-lantigua).